# Вопрос по асинхронному запросу к Postgresql, получение результатов

Tags: python, python-3.x, асинхронность, asyncio, psycopg2

Коллеги, совершенно не понимаю в асинхронном программировании, хочу разобраться, прошу помощи. У меня написан проект с использованием библиотеки `psycopg2`, в качестве интерфейса для Postgresql. Я решил добавить в проект асинхронности, обновил модуль до `psycopg` версии 3, который поддерживает асинхронность и написал простенький пример, чтобы проиллюстрировать мои вопросы.

```
import asyncio
import psycopg
from datetime import datetime

async def main():

    async def open_connection():
        async with await psycopg.AsyncConnection.connect(
                dbname=dbname,
                password=password,
                host='localhost') as aconn:
            async with aconn.cursor() as cur:
                await cur.execute("select count(*) from table_1 join table_2 using (id)")
                print("\nВыполнили запрос к БД")
                return await cur.fetchall()

    async def print_monitor():
        while True:
            print(f'\r{datetime.now()}', end='')
            await asyncio.sleep(0)

    async with asyncio.TaskGroup() as tg:
        task1 = tg.create_task(open_connection())
        task2 = tg.create_task(print_monitor())

asyncio.run(main())
```

В примере две корутины - первая запрашивает базу, вторая постоянно печатает время (просто счетчик времени). Когда ответ на запрос возвращен базой, печатаем "Выполнили...".

**Вопросы** *(Если требуется разбить на два отдельных вопроса - напишите в коментах)*

1. В синхронном коде метод `cursor.fetchall()` возвращает ответ базы (обычно это список кортежей). В асинхронном варианте он возвращает корутину. **Как получить результат?**
2. Как видно из кода, вывод времени не остановится, когда запрос в базу будет выполнен. Есть ли специальные методы в модуле `asyncio` или еще где-то, чтобы получить подтверждение выполнения корутины и, как только она будет выполнена, прервать счетчик. Т. е., мне это видится так, что в условии `while` должен быть некий флаг, срабатывающий по выполнении корутины запроса к базе. Я могу, конечно, ввести `nonlocal` переменную в `main()` и использовать ее в качестве флага, но что-то мне подсказывает, что должны быть какие-то асинхронные инструменты.

**UPT**

Чуть изменю первый вопрос. Во всех доках и примерах написано, что и в асинхронном коде `cursor.fetchall()` должен вернуть результат. А у меня он возвращает корутину, значит что-то я не так написал. Что?

Comment: Как-раз таки метод уже возвращает значение, просто вы его не получаете, вы получаете только таску. Используете `asyncio.gather(task1)`, чтобы получить результат работы `task1`.

Comment: Для выставления флага используйте `asyncio.Event()`.

Comment: @CrazyElf и подтверждением того, что cursor.fetchall() возвращает корутину, а не результат, является то, что если я пытаюсь обратится вот так - cursor.fetchall()[0][0] - то в синхронном варианте я получу то, что ожидаю - первое значение первого кортежа, а в асинхронном я получаю ошибку, что к корутине нельзя так обращаться.

Comment: @CrazyElf Что-то я не то делаю, но не пойму где. Во всех доках и примерах написано что cursor.fetchall() и в асинхронном коде должен возвращать результат. А у меня вот нет.

Comment: Так `await cursor.fetchall()` возвращает результат. Но поскольку у функции `open_connection` стоит модификатор `async`, то уже сама эта функция начинает возвращать корутину, когда вы  делаете `return` результата из этой функции.

Comment: @CrazyElf Даже когда я пытаюсь сделать вот так: `result = await cursor.fetchall()` оно все равно считает `cursor.fetchall()` корутиной. То есть даже если я беру результат **до** `return`. Может у меня новый `psycopg` как-то криво встал?

Comment: Хм, это очень странно, что-то я не понимаю (  Именно `result` получается корутиной? Из вашей фразы не очень понялно. `cursor.fetchall()` - корутина, её нужно делать `await`, чтобы получить из неё результат, но сама эта функция так и останется корутиной. А вот в `result` по идее должен быть результат.

Comment: @CrazyElf * Именно result получается корутиной?* я запутался сам и запутал Вас :( Действительно, если прямо в open_connection() написать result = await cursor.fetchall(), то result это уже результат из базы. Большое спасибо за потраченное время, у меня прояснилось :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте `asyncio.Event()` и `task.result()`:

```py
import asyncio
import psycopg
from datetime import datetime

async def main():

    async def open_connection(event):
        async with await psycopg.AsyncConnection.connect(
                dbname=dbname,
                password=password,
                host='localhost') as aconn:
            async with aconn.cursor() as cur:
                await cur.execute("select count(*) from table_1 join table_2 using (id)")
                print("\nВыполнили запрос к БД")
                event.set()
                return await cur.fetchall()

    async def print_monitor(event):
        while not event.is_set():
            print(f'\r{datetime.now()}', end='')
            await asyncio.sleep(0)

    event = asyncio.Event()
    async with asyncio.TaskGroup() as tg:
        task1 = tg.create_task(open_connection(event))
        task2 = tg.create_task(print_monitor(event))
    print(task1.result())

asyncio.run(main())
```

Comment: С asyncio.Event() - спасибо, работает! С gather вот что меня смущает - во-первых, дока утверждает, что gather устаревший метод выполнения тасков и что TaskGroup() - это его полноценная и более совершенная замена, поэтому мне кажется странным использование gather еще поверх TaskGroup, по логике, TaskGroup() должен полноценно все выполнять. И во-вторых, все равно, так как Вы написали - не работает, оно выводит <_GatheringFuture pending> и все. Результат мы все равно не получаем.

Comment: @AlexeyTrukhanov Да, я не прав. Надо брать `task1.result()`.

Comment: Не работает :( получаем исключение `asyncio.exceptions.InvalidStateError: Result is not set.`

Comment: А, попробуйте убрать одну табуляцию. Таски видимо заканчиваются, когда заканчивается `with`, я поправил код )

Comment: Да! Это успех! :) Только теперь у меня другой вопрос - а что делать, если мне не надо дожидаться окончания тасков. Вот, для этого примера, убираем event, то есть вторая корутина выполняется бесконечно, но когда база вернет нам ответ, мы его должны напечатать (или как-то по-другому использовать в вычислениях). Я этот ответ принимаю, оформлю другой вопрос, чтобы тут не путать. Спасибо!

Comment: @AlexeyTrukhanov Вариантов много разных. Например, запустить какую-то ещё таску, которая сначала делает `await` таске получения данных, а потом печатает результат. `result = await open_connection(); print(result)` в отдельной таске должно работать )

Comment: Да, точно! Большое спасибо, все работает как задумано!